# How to get the file from the folder that contains date in the format of yyyy-mm-dd in its name using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have list of .csv files few of which contains the name with the date formatted as yyyy-mm-dd. I only want those files listed and leave the others.

I tried to use filter on GetChild-Item and use the wildcard however it doesn't generate any outputs. Here's the snippet I'm using:

`Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\csv files\" -Filter "*yyyy-MM-dd.csv"`

I did tried using Where-Object as an alternative to filter however same result. Any pointers what am I doing wrong? Heres's what the sample filename would be like : "2022-01-15.csv"

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

`Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\csv files\" -Filter "*????-??-??.csv"`

Answer (score 0):

This one uses a regular expression. If the date format 'yyyy-MM-dd' is found anywhere in the filename (beginning, middle, or end) it will list it:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\csv files\" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match ".*\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*\.csv"}
```